# How to correctly download file from AWS S3 in Express/React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

I have app where user can upload files to S3 storage. This works fine so far. After that I wanted to add download functionality so I followed each steps from some tutorials for the backend part. When I send download request from the client, the server send me object as a response but the file doesn't download. I'm beginner on this so I have no idea if I made any mistakes on backend code or it's correct but it need to do more thing. Thanks for help.

```
download: function (req, res) {
        const s3 = new aws.S3({
          region: "eu-central-1",
          accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
          secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY
        });
    
        var file = s3
          .getObject({
            Bucket: "my-files",
            Key: example-file
          })
          .createReadStream();
    
       file.pipe(res);
    }
```

Response
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeFaX.png

Comment: You can see in your screenshot that `response.data` is the jpeg image in binary format. The next step is to actually do something with it. I guess you're using axios in your React code? Anyway, the easiest way to start a download is to send the file with an attachment header in express, then simply do `window.location = url;` in your client instead.

Comment: Yes, I use axios. Thank you for the advice anyway. I'll try it.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4800344)

Comment: Hi @VítPaník - did you manage to solve this? I'm having a similar issue.